# Build a php search engine using an array as DB?

Tags: php, arrays, search-engine

new php programmer here, I apologize if this has already been asked:

I have an array filled with strings. Each string is the exact name of a page on my site, so the array is a sort of 'database'.

I'm wondering how to create a search engine that will let the user enter a keyword. The engine will then crawl my array of strings for any matches, and return a list of pages on my site that include the keyword in the pagename.

Any help is appreciated, not sure which functions to use to build this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't you rather search the page contents instead of the page titles?

Comment: Hi Jack, no I'm looking to search titles only.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you could just use `strpos` to see if the users term is contained inside of an array key.  You would have to loop through each page, though, and see if the search term is contained within the pagename.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the tip. I'll do some research on strpos.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is by creating a binary search tree with all the strings. That would make the search faster and more efficient. Here is a [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020738/php-binary-tree-recursion-algorithm) that could help you achieve that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No problem! If it helps, please promote my answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem by using a flat file and conditionals, here is the code:

```
$userlink = $_POST['link_to_test'];
$linkdatabase = array('...');
if (in_array($userlink, $linkdatabase)) 
{
echo 'Data already exists';
}
else { ....
```

Comment: When providing code that solves the problem, it is best to also give at least a short explanation of how it works so that folks reading won't have to mentally parse it line by line to understand the differences.