# Adjacency list Sort algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, binary-tree

I have this kind of adjacency list:

[image: Binary tree]

I need to sort it to this:
2, 7, 9, 10, 8, 16, 17, 11

Basiccaly I have table where I have stored posts with parent ids. I can have unlimited number of levels.

I need just algorithm or full code in PHP.

I tried to use variations of row/column prefixes and some recurrent functions.

Comment: That's a nice looking tree you have there, but it's not nice enough for us to do this for you. Stackoverflow is here to help you with specific coding issues. If you give it a shot yourself and come back with any issues you run across, we will be more than happy to help; however "I need just algorithm or full code in php" shows you've tried nothing and put in no research.

Comment: That doesn't look much like a binary tree to me. What you've got there is an adjacency list - there are plenty of guides about parsing one (either in PHP or pseudocode).

Comment: @iainn doesn't a binary tree "branch" off whereas an adjacency list is just a single "road"? This looks like a binary tree to me.

Comment: OP look at how this guy asked a similar question in regards to binary tree; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020738/php-binary-tree-recursion-algorithm

Comment: A node in a binary tree can only have two child nodes, left and right.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i finally did it. I was idi*t.

```
public function makeTree($parent_id = 0, &$array = array())
{
   // Get results where parent_id == $parent_id
  $recepts = $this->recept->get()->where("parent_id =" . $parent_id);
   // Foreach through them
   foreach ($recepts as $recept) {
     // Add this to array
     array_push($array, $recept);
     // Repeat
     $this->makeTree($recept["id"], $array);
   }
   return $array;
}
```